# Oracle how to do outer join in line select

Tags: oracle

I have three selects

```
 SELECT
        mam.fecha                                                              fecha
      , u.COD_USUARIO                                                          usuario
      , u.NOMBREAPELLIDOS                                                      nombre                                                      
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha ASC)  AS rn_asc
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha DESC) AS rn_desc
      ,mam.accion   accion

      ,u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION centrogestion 
    FROM r_mod_asignar_material mam
    INNER JOIN r_usuarios u ON mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario

    where  mam.ACCION = 'A'

    and trunc(mam.fecha) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
   and mam.cod_usuario = '9717703'
   and u.id_centro_gestion = '3'
   order by u.cod_usuario
```

Second one, it is the same changing the where

```
SELECT
        mam.fecha                                                              fecha
      , u.COD_USUARIO                                                          usuario
      , u.NOMBREAPELLIDOS                                                      nombre                                                      
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha ASC)  AS rn_asc
      , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario ORDER BY mam.fecha DESC) AS rn_desc
      ,mam.accion   accion

      ,u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION centrogestion 
    FROM r_mod_asignar_material mam
    INNER JOIN r_usuarios u ON mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario

    where  mam.ACCION = 'D'

    and trunc(mam.fecha) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy')
   and mam.cod_usuario = '9717703'
   and u.id_centro_gestion = '3'
   order by u.cod_usuario
```

Thrid one

```
SELECT   COUNT (*) numeroincidencias, ri.cod_usuario usuario
            FROM r_incidencias ri
           WHERE TRUNC (ri.fecha_inc) = TO_DATE ('13/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
           and ri.cod_usuario = '9717703'
        GROUP BY ri.cod_usuario
```

I want to link these select by  cod_usuario. It couldn't be rows in the first, second or third select.

How can I do an outer join of these selects?

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 1):

Make each of your selects a common table expression, then full outer join them together:

```
WITH cte1 AS (SELECT mam.fecha AS fecha,
                     u.COD_USUARIO AS usuario,
                     u.NOMBREAPELLIDOS AS nombre,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario
                                        ORDER BY mam.fecha ASC) AS rn_asc,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario
                                        ORDER BY mam.fecha DESC) AS rn_desc,
                     mam.accion AS accion,
                     u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION AS centrogestion 
                FROM r_mod_asignar_material mam
                INNER JOIN r_usuarios u
                  ON mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
                where mam.ACCION = 'A' and
                      trunc(mam.fecha) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') AND
                      mam.cod_usuario = '9717703' AND
                      u.id_centro_gestion = '3'
                order by u.cod_usuario),
     cte2 AS (SELECT mam.fecha AS fecha,
                     u.COD_USUARIO AS usuario,
                     u.NOMBREAPELLIDOS AS nombre,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario
                                        ORDER BY mam.fecha ASC) AS rn_asc,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY u.cod_usuario
                                        ORDER BY mam.fecha DESC) AS rn_desc,
                     mam.accion AS accion
                     u.ID_CENTRO_GESTION AS centrogestion 
                FROM r_mod_asignar_material mam
                INNER JOIN r_usuarios u
                  ON mam.cod_usuario = u.cod_usuario
                where mam.ACCION = 'D' and
                      trunc(mam.fecha) = to_date('13/09/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') AND
                      mam.cod_usuario = '9717703' AND
                      u.id_centro_gestion = '3'
                order by u.cod_usuario),
     cte3 AS (SELECT COUNT (*) numeroincidencias,
                     ri.cod_usuario usuario
                FROM r_incidencias ri
                WHERE TRUNC (ri.fecha_inc) = TO_DATE ('13/09/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND
                      ri.cod_usuario = '9717703'
                GROUP BY ri.cod_usuario)
SELECT *
  FROM cte1
  FULL OUTER JOIN cte2
    ON cte2.cod_usuario = cte1.cod_usuario
  FULL OUTER JOIN cte3
    ON cte3.cod_usuario = COALESCE(cte1.cod_usuario, cte2.cod_usuario)
```